# Is there a loop that will calculate the better value of an unlimited amount of products?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So currently, I am aiming to create a code that helps customers at shops, find which product has better value.

However, the code should be as simple, short and elegant as possible. And that's a bit of a problem for me.

I am supposed to have a code that can calculate the value of an *unlimited amount* of products, but I don't know how to do that, so that's why I had to do everything manually, and could only create a code that calculates the better value of up to 10 products only.

Could I receive any tips maybe?

```
products = int(input("How many products are there? "))
if products > 10:
  print("This code can only take up to 10 product sizes.")
  print("Please enter only up to 10 product sizes below.")
if products <= 1:
  print("You must enter at least two product sizes to compare.")
if products >= 1:
  cost1 = float(input("Cost of first product($): "))
  mass1 = float(input("Mass of first product(g): "))
  ans1 = cost1/mass1
  a = ans1
  ans2 = ""
  ans3 = ""
  ans4 = ""
  ans5 = ""
  ans6 = ""
  ans7 = ""
  ans8 = ""
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 2:
  cost2 = float(input("Cost of second product($): "))
  mass2 = float(input("Mass of second product(g): "))
  ans2 = cost2/mass2
  if a > ans2:
    a = ans2
if products >= 3:
  cost3 = float(input("Cost of third product($): "))
  mass3 = float(input("Mass of third product(g): "))
  ans3 = cost3/mass3
  if a > ans3:
    a = ans3
  ans4 = ""
  ans5 = ""
  ans6 = ""
  ans7 = ""
  ans8 = ""
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 4:
  cost4 = float(input("Cost of fourth product($): "))
  mass4 = float(input("Mass of fourth product(g): "))
  ans4 = cost4/mass4
  if a > ans4:
    a = ans4
  ans5 = ""
  ans6 = ""
  ans7 = ""
  ans8 = ""
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 5:
  cost5 = float(input("Cost of fifth product($): "))
  mass5 = float(input("Mass of fifth product(g): "))
  ans5 = cost5/mass5
  if a > ans5:
    a = ans5
  ans6 = ""
  ans7 = ""
  ans8 = ""
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 6:
  cost6 = float(input("Cost of sixth product($): "))
  mass6 = float(input("Mass of sixth product(g): "))
  ans6 = cost6/mass6
  if a > ans6:
    a = ans6
  ans7 = ""
  ans8 = ""
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 7:
  cost7 = float(input("Cost of seventh product($): "))
  mass7 = float(input("Mass of seventh product(g): "))
  ans7 = cost7/mass7
  if a > ans7:
    a = ans7
  ans8 = ""
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 8:
  cost8 = float(input("Cost of eighth product($): "))
  mass8 = float(input("Mass of eighth product(g): "))
  ans8 = cost8/mass8
  if a > ans8:
    a = ans8
  ans9 = ""
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 9:
  cost9 = float(input("Cost of ninth product($): "))
  mass9 = float(input("Mass of ninth product(g): "))
  ans9 = cost9/mass9
  if a > ans9:
    a = ans9
  ans10 = ""
if products >= 10:
  cost10 = float(input("Cost of tenth product($): "))
  mass10 = float(input("Mass of tenth product(g): "))
  ans10 = cost10/mass10
  if a > ans10:
    a = ans10
if products >= 1:
  print("The product(s) with the best value is/are the below product number(s):")
  if ans1 == a:
    print(1)
  if ans2 == a:
    print(2)
  if ans3 == a:
    print(3)
  if ans4 == a:
    print(4)
  if ans5 == a:
    print(5)
  if ans6 == a:
    print(6)
  if ans7 == a:
    print(7)
  if ans8 == a:
    print(8)
  if ans9 == a:
    print(9)
  if ans10 == a:
    print(10)
  print("The cost per gram is ${}/g".format(a))
```

Comment: learn about python lists and for loops.

Comment: @AlbinPaul I have, but I still don't know how I should create a code, because I just do not know where to start

Comment: Try to follow a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/  to learn python. You are looking for _loops_ and _list_'s - code like your current one simply is not feasible for "unlimited" inputs.

Comment: You have the amount of products stored in `products`. You want to ask the user for input and make a calculation for each and every product. Start with `for i in range(len(products)):` and try to build on that

Comment: @user13259935 create a list for mass and cost first for a start then use for loops to do some calculations.

Comment: Also, regarding this website, your question right now seems like it is asking for a solution for your homework. Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Take a moment to read about [ask] and most importantly about how to provide a [mre]. We don't even need to know this is a school project. You should present a coding problem - as minimal as possible - show what you tried and ask for help with it

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry, I just don't have that much experience because I'm pretty new. I'll read those links and improve for future references. Sorry again.

Comment: No need to be sorry. We are here to help. My comment is not to scold you, but to help you improve the question to try and receive helpful answers (and also just to be on-topic on this site...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it. You should study the standard data types and standard operations intensively and enough examples of use.

```
# This list stores products as tuples (cost, mass)
# Just add tuples if you want to have more products
products = [(2.0, 300), (1.7, 250), (3.8, 480), (1.9, 225)]

best = None

# Use a for loop to iterate over the products
for product in products:

    # unpack the tuple
    cost, mass = product

    # calculate the ratio
    ratio = float(cost/mass)

    # see if its better than the best
    # 'not best' just checks for the case that best == None
    if not best or ratio > float(best[0]/best[1]):
        best = product

print("The best product is: {0}".format(best))
```

Answer (score 1):

first off think about looping. for loops, while loops, etc

```
count = -1
while count < 0:
  try:
    count = int(input("How many products are there? "))
  except ValueError:
    # meaningful error for invalid options, # catches non integer values
    print("  Please try again: inputs must be a positive integers")
    continue
  if count < 0:
    print("  Please try again: inputs must be a positive integers")
```

once you capture how many products you want. you need to loop to gather all the cost and mass values for a product and store it into something that can easily be accessed.

This makes me think of an array.

```
products = []
```

now loop over and capture the data values for cost and mass

```
# loop over to capture data
for i in range(0,count):

  # again loop for positive values
  cost = -1
  while cost < 0:
    try:
      cost = float(input("How much does product "+str(i+1)+" cost? "))
    except ValueError:
      # meaningful error for invalid options, # catches non integer values
      print("  Please try again: inputs must be a positive float")
      continue
    if cost < 0:
      print("  Please try again: inputs must be a positive float")

  mass = -1
  while mass < 0:
    try:
      mass = float(input("How much does product "+str(i+1)+" weight? "))
    except ValueError:
      # meaningful error for invalid options, # catches non integer values
      print("  Please try again: inputs must be a positive float")
      continue
    if mass < 0:
      print("  Please try again: inputs must be a positive float")
  # append to cost and mass into the products array as an array of to values
  products.append([cost,mass])

# test the output
print(products
```

This should be a good enough jumping off point. Now you have captured all the data for any amount of products, you can access it later.

```
print(products[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is something you looking for,

```
def best_cost():
    while True:
        num_of_products = int(input('enter no.of products:'))
        if num_of_products < 1:
            print('enter valid number for number of products')
        else:
            print(f'finding best value out of {num_of_products} products')
            all_prices = []
            for i in range(1, num_of_products+1):
                cost = float(input(f'enter cost of prod {i} in $:'))
                mass = float(input(f'enter mass of prod {i} in grms:'))
                print(f'cost of product {i} for {mass}grms is {cost}$')
                price = cost/mass
                all_prices.append(price)
            for prod in all_prices:
                if prod == min(all_prices):
                    best_prod = all_prices.index(prod)+1
            return f'best product is {best_prod}'
best_cost()
```

you need more practice.